# Image not scaling smaller as the resolution decreases

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. This is my code.

HTML

```
<div class="choose1 hidden-xl hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><a href="#"><img src="img/app_store.png" alt=""  style="height:auto; width:220px;" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><a href="#" ><img src="img/google_play.png" alt=""  style="height:auto; width:220px;" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:5px;"><a href="#" ><img src="img/amazon.png" alt="" style="height:auto; width:220px;" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.choose1 {
    background: url('img/slides/1mobile.png') top center no-repeat;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

When I check the image on small screen, the banner does becomes small, instead it slips out of the div. Please check the live site [here](http://www.colorpeutic.com/) **on small screen**. WHat should I do so that the image transforms as much as the div is.

Comment: Which image are you talking about?

Comment: The background image of `.choose1`

Comment: The image should remain within the red border.

Comment: I checked on 320px and it is within the red border.

Comment: check it on 150px or so..

Comment: why you want it on 150px when 320px is the minimum?

Comment: Actually 320 is the height, not width.

Comment: I just want that on xs screen, my background image stays inside red border.. no matter what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
.choose1 {
background: url('img/slides/1mobile.png') top center no-repeat;
border: 1px solid red;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm.

Comment: `background-size: contain;` will give you the exact same result in this case.